# encodeWithCoder Not getting called

Tags: objective-c, decode, encode, nskeyedarchiver

I have an object (testSession) that complies to NSCoder and when I use:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:testSession toFile:filename];
```

It has:

```
@interface Session : NSObject <NSCoding> {
```

and has encodeWithCoder: and initWithCoder: functions. Neither are getting called. What would prevent this?

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
```

Do these need to be declared in the header?

Comment: Since your class conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, you do not need to declare the methods in your header.

Comment: I haven't been. So what would prevent encodeWithCoder: from being called?

Answer (score 1):

WHOOPS! I forgot to retain my testSession object after creating it. I'm a tad rusty :P